# How to use Facebook as a gateway to my Website

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a website (php, mysql) by which users can register to the database via a form & login via a login form.

Alternatively I have a Facebook Login Button that I want to allow users to :

1. Simply click
2. Direct them to Facebook
3. Accept my websites permissions
4. Redirect them back to my website fully logged in with the ability to use the functionality of the website.

I currently have the following code that sends does the above, apart from actually logging them in / storing their data in my database:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout_fb'])){
    session_destroy();
}

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '../../inc/lib/fb/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . './../../inc/lib/fb/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

$app_id = 'app_id';
$app_secret = 'app_secret';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.test.com/tests/fb_test/facebook-sdk-test.php');

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} 
else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

The above returns the following output:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => test_id [email] => test@email.co.uk [first_name] => Test [gender] => male [last_name] => Name [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/user_id/ [locale] => en_GB [name] => Test Name [timezone] => 1 [updated_time] => 2015-06-06T13:31:40+0000 [verified] => 1 ) )
```

How can I further my application so that the user can:

- See their name, profile picture in the same way I use it in my website
- Store their information in the websites database so that it can be easily retreived again (is this needed, if not what alternative do I have?)
- Logout

Can anyone describe a solution to what I have stated. I'm struggling to understand the logic needed, to create this other means of entry into my website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the recommended approach is to separate (1) user (2) login method. So instead of thinking "How do I show a user's profile picture if they logged in via Facebook?" just think "How do I show a user's profile picture?".

For example, you might have a "user" table (with name, username, etc) and an "auth" table. If the user registered with a username/password then the "auth" table will have a row with their (hashed) password. If they logged in using Facebook then the "auth" table will have a row with their Facebook User ID and access token.

These two (or more) login methods can be used together. For example, they might have registered with a username and password. But they come back to your website and log in using Facebook. You can just add a row to the "auth" table for the user so now they can log in using password *or* Facebook.

**So, how would I add Facebook login to your website?**

When the user is redirected from Facebook to your website after logging in:

1. Call `/me` with the access token to validate it and get the user's ID
2. If the `auth` table contains a row for this Facebook user then log them in (e.g. by creating a session as you would normally)
3. If the `auth` table doesn't contain a row for the Facebook user then create a new `user` row and `auth` row (you might need to show a form and ask them to confirm some details such as name/email/photo)